# Script that refreshes importrange internal error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

So as every other person, I keep getting importrange internal error on some of my files due to many data is getting imported. In order to avoid this, I'm thinking if someone can help me to make a script that refreshes the links in certain tab without taking the format and to place the same links again that the tab had before.

Can someone assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the method [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to fix this type of issue. You can create a simple Google Apps Script calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

Since `Flush` will "Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes." You can test the Apps script:

```
function flushErros() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

You can run the script 3 options:

**Option 1:**
If you need to apply the fix in all the sheets within a Google Spreadsheet. You can create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui) to call the flush. Here is a simple example:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Fix import errors')
    .addItem('Refresh Sheet', 'flushErros')
    .addToUi();
}
```

**Option 2:**

If you are going to apply it to only one sheet within a Google Spreadsheet. You can create a button and link the script to it but following the steps:

1. Inset an image over the cell.

[image]

2. Assign a script by clicking the 3 dots in the image.

[image]

3. Add the name of the function.

[image]

**Option 3:**
Add a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) when the sheet is edited or open by following the steps:

1. Open your Apps Script project, and at the left select "Trigger."

[image]

2. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.

[image]